# Adjust AutoScroll scrollbars to hide at specific form size

Tags: c#, forms, autoscroll

I've got a form with few panels that are filled with controls (still plenty of space on the bottom and right).
The form has AutoScroll set to true, however, the scrollbars seem to appear whenever the form is under maximum possible size (1932, 980 in my case).

I figure I can just write the code to check the form size and manually hide the scrollbars when form exceeds a certain size (or all controls are visible), however, I want to keep such work-arounds as such for the last resort.

Is there a property or a setting that adjusts the visible area of a form and/or manipulate the appearance of the scrollbars at specific form sizes?

Comment: How are you resizing your panels? A mistake I've made in the past is not accounting for the border around the form, and using, say, half of the form's width for each panel. Post a picture of your form if possible, and some code on how you initialize and resize your controls.

Comment: As I was extracting initialization code I found a lost panel on the bottom of the screen, which was basically invisible content... Anyway, thank you for the pointer, it would probably take me long to find this error on my own.

Comment: Good! You should post and accept your solution as an answer here to help out any others who run into the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out I had an empty panel on the bottom of my form, which was causing the problem.
Removing it fixed the issue.